# PWA not finding javascript files in directories

Tags: javascript, tomcat, oracle-apex, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying for a while now to create a PWA in Oracle APEX by following some instructions on http://vmorneau.me/apex-pwa-part4/, but I'm having no luck in certain parts.

I've installed the demo to test it and see what's wrong, but I'm having the same issues with the demo app, namely some important files not being detected/found when I run it. I thought I had configured something wrong previously, but this time it was supposed to work properly.

Example, I have the app.js inside the js directory in Apex:

[image: Static Application Files]
When I run the app, I get these messages:

[image]
I tried checking the file path the same way I tried to see if the manifest.json file was in the proper root folder, and it couldn't be found:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a common problem I see on the forums, that doesn't relate to the PWA concept. You'll probably find the same thing if you tried to refer to static files loaded into the workspace.

See Morten's example regarding a fixing the configuration
https://ora-00001.blogspot.com/2016/12/apex-plugin-files-and-404-not-found-in-ords.html

Or placed your files in the middle tier, using /i/ (or preferrably a custom location /c/)